# How do I avoid creating a nil reference in Lua when I remove an item from a table?

Tags: lua, null, lua-table, love2d

I am new to Lua, and I'm trying to create a video game using LOVE2D in which the player decorates pizzas moving on a conveyer belt. Once the player successfully builds a pizza, they receive a new order and automatically begin working on the next pizza.

The issue I'm having is with keeping track of the pizza objects the player interacts with. I've created a table to hold the pizzas, where the item at the first index is the current pizza--the one the player can add toppings to. To save memory, I thought of removing the pizza at the first index (table.remove(pizzas, 1)) once it leaves the screen. However, this results in the error 'attempt to index a nil value', which I'm guessing is because I have multiple references to the item at the first index (e.g. to keep track of position, pizzas[1].x, or to keep track of cheese, I have pizzas[1].cheeseCount). How do I avoid this? Thanks so much!

Comment: how do you transition to the next pizza?

Comment: @Nifim I set pizzas[1] = pizzas[2], then removed the first item by table.remove(pizzas, 1).

Comment: when you call `table.remove` it will reorder your array for you. no need to set `pizzas[1] = pizzas[2]` https://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html

Answer (score 2):

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove

> **table.remove (list [, pos])**
>
> Removes from list the element at position pos, returning the value of the removed element. When pos is
> an integer between 1 and #list, it shifts down the elements
> list[pos+1], list[pos+2], ···, list[#list] and erases element
> list[#list]; The index pos can also be 0 when #list is 0, or #list +
> 1; in those cases, the function erases the element list[pos].
>
> The default value for pos is #list, so that a call table.remove(l)
> removes the last element of list l.

So your problem is most likely  not that you index the first (removed) pizza, but that you index a pizza that has been shifted down and hence does no longer exist at its original index.

```
local pizzas = {"A", "B", "C"}
table.remove(pizzas, 1)
```

now your table looks like that: `{"B", "C"}`

and `pizzas[3]` would be `nil`.